# Kendo UI scheduler create

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Im having problems with the kendo scheduler. Im using it together with AngularJS.
When i create an event and click save, first of the create window wont close and when i manually close it the event is not there. But if i reload the page the event is shown there, so it is getting saved to the database.

Scheduler dataSource:

```
 var dataSource = {
        transport: {
            read: read,
            create: create,
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
            },
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "occurrenceId",
                fields: {
                    occurrenceId: { from: "occurrenceId", type: "number" },
                    title: { from: "title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                    start: { type: "date", from: "start" },
                    end: { type: "date", from: "end" },
                    description: { from: "description" },
                    recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                    recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                    recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                    isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

And here is the create function:

```
function create(data) {

        var occurrence = {
            "title": data.data.title,
            "start": data.data.start,
            "end": data.data.end,
            "description": data.data.description,
            "recurrenceId": data.data.recurrenceId,
            "recurrenceRule": data.data.recurrenceRule,
            "recurrenceException": data.data.recurrenceException,
            "isAllDay": data.data.isAllDay,
            "ownerId": $scope.resource.id
        }

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/occurrences',
                data: JSON.stringify(occurrence),
                contentType: "application/json"
            }).success(function (response) {
                response.data
            });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the inserted data (including the generated ID) from your create function. On your http post's success, it doesn't seem to be doing anything meaningful.

From [Kendo-UI data source API reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.create): The remote service must return the inserted data items and the data item field configured as the id must be set. For example if the id of the data item is ProductID the "create" server response must be [{ "ProductID": 79 }].